# WordPress: deleted page still showing up

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress 4.6 with Divi theme.

A project page behaved funny so I deleted it.
Now I wanted to build it again with the same slug, but the deleted page still shows up under that slug.

- I deleted the trash
- I deleted the browser cache
- even opened an incognito tab in Chrome

I even changed the slug at the time the old page appeared. Now the deleted page still shows up. But under the NEW slug.

Completely lost here.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually deleted the page, and not just left it in 'Bin' or 'Trash'?

If you're logged in as Admin, I believe deleted, and draft pages still show as normal so you can preview them.

Try logging out of /wp-admin/ and see if you can still access the page. If it says 'Page not found', then your page is still in Wordpress and hasn't been deleted.

Comment: I can still see it. The funny thing. If I make a new page with the same slug the old page shows up.
I deleted the old page and emptied the trash.

Comment: So the page with that slug, is no where in your Admin area, anywhere? Ist must be a caching issue then, or something else is going on.

Comment: Nowhere to be seen, no.

Comment: If you add a new page, something completley unrelated... and try to view it, are you able to?

Comment: Yes. That's possible.

Comment: Gotta be something else going on. Disabled all plugins, like i said, logged out? Strange thing is that if you did completely delete it, and it was still in the trash or bin, then a new page with the same slug wouldn't be possible, it would force it to be `-2`. I'm still going to say it's probably a caching issue. You might need to close the question, as it doesn't look like it's going to be resolved here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121766/discussion-between-stnbrk-and-lee).

Answer (score 0):

In Appearance > Theme Options > Front Page Section 1 Content you can edit what pages show on that first scrolling screen. This also drove me mad for a while till I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem because an image had the same name as a page.